# Android: Load image on launch from URL

Tags: android, url, image-load

I am a learner and have been working on a home visitor app to get image from a URL of the visitor. Using the following code, which I found online, I was able to load image by adding an intent before the screen and adding a button on the screen saying "See Visitor Image" but now I want that my image should load as soon as the app launches. What changes could I make to do that? Thanks for your help.

```
OnClickListener getImageBtnOnClick = new OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View view) {
        Context context = view.getContext();
        Editable ed = inputUrl.getText();
        Drawable image = ImageOperations(context,ed.toString(),"image.jpg");
        ImageView imgView = new ImageView(context);
        imgView = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.image1);
        imgView.setImageDrawable(image);
    }
};

public void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {
    super.onCreate(icicle);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    inputUrl = ((EditText)findViewById(R.id.imageUrl));
    inputUrl.setSingleLine();
    inputUrl.setTextSize(11);
    Button getImageButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.getImageButton);
    getImageButton.setOnClickListener(getImageBtnOnClick);

}   

private Drawable ImageOperations(Context ctx, String url, String saveFilename) {
    try {
        InputStream is = (InputStream) this.fetch(url);
        Drawable d = Drawable.createFromStream(is, "src");
        return d;
    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    }
}

public Object fetch(String address) throws MalformedURLException,IOException {
    URL url = new URL(address);
    Object content = url.getContent();
    return content;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make use of SmartImageView, it is a drop-in replacement for Android’s standard ImageView which additionally allows images to be loaded from URLs or the user’s contact address book. Images are cached to memory and to disk for super fast loading.

https://github.com/loopj/android-smart-image-view

Or on OnResume of ur activity start downloading the image form the url as u r doing now in the click listener of button in a separate thread to avoid blocking main UI thread. Once you completed the download you can update the image view using handler from the worker thread.

You can make use of async task also instead of creating your own thread and handler to update UI. for more infor about async task refer following link http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidPerformance/article.html

Comment: Oh Nice! This should make my work so much easier. I have been reading Vogella's site alongside my learning too. I am a little confused about the concept of threads though. They still confuse me. Is there a place where I can read about threads in detail? Everything I found so far says almost the same things with little difference as if they were all copied from the same book.

Comment: you can google it out. For async task - you have to override following  methods. onpreExecute() - ui changes to be done before start downloading  image such as showing progress dialog doinBackground - download the image , onpostExecute() - ui changes after downloading image suc as dismissing progress dialog

Comment: I have tried to use the SmartImageView but something or the else goes wrong. When the app launches I cannot see anything where the SmartImageView should be.

Comment: Can you please post your layout file and activity code? It will help others to identify the issue.

Comment: For your info  you can check out the following link to get more idea about threading concepts in android http://www.slideshare.net/andersgoransson/efficient-android-threading#btnPrevious. It is really useful.

Comment: Thanks very much. I had identified the problem. It seems that the URL cannot be passed directly as shown in the documentation but instead it works perfectly fine if you store it in a string and pass it as an argument to fetch the image from that URL. Thanks very much for the link on Threads. It has a lot of other slideshows that are very helpful to me.